# QGIS: Error code showed up after Landsat 8 TOA and crashed the program (SCP plugin)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, scp

Trying to get all bands corrected but it failed every single time in version 3.10 or 3.16.

Error codes showed as below:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after I tried to troubleshoot for days, my conclusion is this plugin is not so friendly for macos (Big Sur). I thought my gdal installation had some issues, but nothing wrong with them in reality. In general, it just a compatibility kind of issue. After I downgraded to SCP 6.4.7, everything works again!